# Open a new link in already opened tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, window

When I open a new tab using the window.open method, I want to programmatically change the URL of that tab (which is already open).

Let's take an example I have opened a new tab google.com and saved it like this
`let a = window.open('https://google.com','_blank')`
then I want that I open a new link which is bing.com in the same (a)

I have used window.location for it but did not work